# Which XUL element to use when a url is entered and loaded for calling JS?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I am developing a Firefox add-on using XUL Overlay and want to call a specific js when the current page loads after entering the URL. I want to know which XUL element would be affected and should be used to call said JS, such as page or tab or window or ??? Also, which event would be best for the element? Or is my logic wrong?
Also,the js's function is to record tab title and/or url so i need to know when to call js and with corresponding event. Thanks.. :)

Comment: Which exact notification are you interested in? a) user enters a URL. b) location display in the URL bar changes. c) a page finishes loading. d) something else. Alternatively you can edit your post to explain what you need this for - this might also help understanding what you need.

Comment: Ok,ill go with c) when a page finishes loading.
The add-on records the tab's title and it needs to do this every time a new page loads somewhat like a history catcher. So,to call the js to do this task,i need to know where to call said js, and with what event. Thanks,i will edit it...

Comment: On second thought,i guess b)location display in the URL bar changes
would suit my needs better...it doesn't matter if the page loads or not,as long as i can get the url and/or tab title. Thanks for your interest, Wladimir :)

Answer (score 0):

The XUL element you should be watching is the [tabbrowser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser). In the browser window (which means also in overlays applied to the browser window) it can be accessed via the global `gBrowser` variable. If you want to know when a page finishes loading you can listen to the `DOMContentLoaded` event. Something like this (untested code):

```js
// Declare an own namespace for extension's functions to avoid
// name conflicts with other extensions.
var MyExtension = {};

MyExtension.init = function()
{
  gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", MyExtension.onPageLoad, false);
};

MyExtension.onPageLoad = function(event)
{
  // Get the document that loaded
  var doc = event.originalTarget;

  // Ignore frames that load
  if (doc.defaultView != doc.defaultView.parent)
    return;

  // Ignore if this isn't the active tab
  var browser = gBrowser.getBrowserForDocument(doc);
  if (browser != gBrowser.selectedBrowser)
    return;

  alert("Page loaded in current tab: " + doc.defaultView.location.href);
};

// Wait for the browser window to finish loading before adding event listeners
window.addEventListener("load", MyExtension.init, false);
```

If you want to get notified earlier, when the address displayed in the URL bar changes, you can use a [progress listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners) instead. You want to implement the method `onLocationChange` of the progress listener and leave the other methods empty. Note that this method is also called when the user switches to a different tab (this also causes a location bar change). Also: the parameter `aURI` passed to `onLocationChange` is an [`nsIURI` instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIURI). If you want the URL as a string you should look at `aURI.spec`.

Comment: Thanks Wladimir, but i don't think this is what i was looking for...
What would the code be in the XUL file to call the js? Also,in the case,i'm being an idiot, can the code you gave be used in the XUL file? cause as far as i know,its kinda like html code,right?
Also,realized you're the guy who made ABP!...,big fan,oblivious though! :)

Comment: @user1344667: XUL is purely a markup language. You are asking about dynamic behavior - this is implemented with JavaScript. The JavaScript code above can be included into a XUL file with the usual `<script>` tag.